# Installing node npm keeps bringing up error message

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, multer, multer-gridfs-storage

I’m installing these npm packages:

```
npm I express body-parser bcrypt cors dotenv gridfs-stream multer multer-gridfs-storage helmet morgan jsonwebtoken mongoose
```

However, I keep getting an error whenever I download them. It’s an error that states:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: sanab@1.0.0
npm ERR! Found: multer@1.4.5-lts.1
npm ERR! node_modules/multer
npm ERR!   multer@"^1.4.5-lts.1" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer multer@"^1.4.2" from multer-gridfs-storage@5.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/multer-gridfs-storage
npm ERR!   multer-gridfs-storage@"^5.0.2" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

What do I do?

I keep trying to install these npm packages but all I keep getting back is this error message

Comment: Can you share your `package.json`?

Answer (score 0):

Out of curiosity have you tried installing each individually? I’ve had issues in the past where installing a variety of things at once I had typos and/or issues with the download.

Maybe you could find a certain package providing the error.

Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is due to `gridfs-stream` installation. What you can do is from your commad just remove `gridfs-stream` and execute it. After it’s execution, you can use:

```bash
npm i gridfs-stream -legacy-peer-deps
```

This will surely solve your issue.
Make sure to upvote this answer.